# Creating sf Linestrings from Points

Tags: r, gis, line, spatial, r-sf

I am trying to create sf Linestrings from a Point dataframe. I already found this thread on GitHub [creating lines form points w/ grouping](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/321) which was very helpful (in the end I also want the grouping to create several lines) but sadly this didn't work for me. I tried recreating the approach but I still get lines that are jagged because the line jumps between points from left to right and not in the right order:

[image]

This is how I am creating the lines:

```
test_lines <- data.frame(x, y, NEW_ID, LINE_ID)

new_lines <- test_lines %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 25832) %>%
  group_by(NEW_ID) %>%
  dplyr::summarize() %>%  # do_union=FALSE doesn't work as well
  st_cast("LINESTRING") 

plot(new_lines[1,])
```

And this is my example data:

```
     x <- c(512479.697065708 , 512480.250661712 , 512482.987040812 , 512483.249553425 , 512492.586731394 , 512490.200111953 , 512489.78343994 ,  512489.450950014 ,
     512488.95288015 ,  512488.542001041 , 512488.167317277 , 512487.098424994 , 512485.96381862 ,  512484.828296161 , 512484.185293151 , 512483.723459029 ,
     512483.512066037 , 512483.249553425 , 512415.384159413 , 512415.577936111 , 512415.789227095 , 512415.894862411 , 512416.791584063 , 512417.027661192 ,
     512417.241952151 , 512417.521992658 , 512417.693089591 , 512417.947047717 , 512418.134676398 , 512418.436225651 , 512418.85206217 ,  512419.168545053 ,
     512419.444117332 , 512419.77909383 ,  512420.049782357 , 512420.359461634 , 512420.657619221 , 512421.028816685 , 512421.320003802 , 512421.596095004 ,
     512422.029521903 , 512422.369220085 , 512422.733380085 , 512423.120268537 , 512423.528349138 , 512423.956056845 , 512426.471454705 , 512426.973087944 ,
     512427.901722061 , 512428.039719761 , 512479.697065708 , 512479.143469704 , 512478.952871949 , 512478.136753726 , 512477.662498739 , 512476.836567475 ,
     512476.544938521 , 512475.969742769 , 512474.651534452 , 512474.039156801 , 512472.772119656 , 512472.062125426 , 512470.870109725 , 512470.2573916 ,  
     512469.128985774 , 512468.096017977 , 512467.564167915 , 512466.865294995 , 512466.320281231 , 512465.699030065 , 512465.046371911 , 512464.414069958 ,
     512463.650878563 , 512462.067272335 , 512459.664316558 , 512457.08817566 ,  512454.508070211 , 512453.210570318 , 512452.290456146 , 512450.858545348 ,
     512449.245135025 , 512447.211963124 , 512445.045315604 , 512444.173996014 , 512443.497085307 , 512442.300040917 , 512441.645461029 , 512440.920296171 ,
     512440.288043701 , 512439.578990257 , 512439.045057906 , 512438.355723944 , 512437.770398522 , 512437.184200194 , 512436.300526718 , 512435.233306577 ,
     512434.470977573 , 512433.299213609 , 512432.598626104 , 512432.056047379 , 512431.729465245 , 512431.169762474 , 512428.039719761 , 512428.177717462 ,
     512429.855871946 , 512430.610059703 , 512431.169762474 , 512507.157200324 , 512506.769961235 , 512506.429383907 , 512506.036085093 , 512505.629745321 ,
     512505.13325311 ,  512504.715807742 , 512504.408778062 , 512503.982592299 , 512503.493855094 , 512503.061600461 , 512502.830877652 , 512502.39535427 , 
     512502.156304005 , 512501.720234171 , 512501.219812837 , 512500.699217728 , 512500.37348907 ,  512499.94418624 ,  512499.267964737 , 512498.760247967 ,
     512498.340938622 , 512497.680562224 , 512497.252821696 , 512496.367080671 , 512495.34381091 ,  512494.487636641 , 512492.010959641 , 512489.961273602 ,
     512488.853605089 , 512488.341336553 , 512485.388097999 , 512484.826397199 , 512483.313981521 , 512481.264552167 , 512480.282029173 , 512479.197741063 ,
     512478.70867489 ,  512478.188488126 , 512477.719910045 , 512477.109664291 , 512475.780561418 , 512473.898753897 , 512472.978044594 , 512472.28686614 , 
     512472.166699147 , 512471.794914526 , 512471.012634321 , 512531.077743031 , 512531.469757789 , 512532.669683117 , 512532.680756732 , 512532.708711943 ,
     512532.752157013 , 512532.867686974 , 512533.132446696 , 512533.371046309 , 512533.824055231 , 512534.024504623 , 512534.40306935 ,  512535.131292432 ,
     512535.705843865 , 512536.399961217 , 512536.617626863 , 512536.92069792 ,  512537.15235619 ,  512537.410472921 , 512537.980240068 , 512538.271128349 ,
     512538.604521918 , 512539.42394453 ,  512540.592798016 , 512541.567214129 , 512542.001164023 , 512542.206911238 , 512542.592928084 , 512543.728893019 ,
     512544.068808613 , 512544.387303822 , 512544.785527888 , 512545.053449377 , 512545.547078128 , 512546.111529726 , 512547.18679658 ,  512547.690398632 ,
     512547.767937038 , 512547.804141347 , 512547.827013442 , 512548.285361443 , 512548.887017059 , 512549.195740681 , 512531.077743031 , 512530.685728273 ,
     512530.543579968 , 512530.197928509 , 512529.632024297 , 512529.337251287 , 512528.538408127 , 512528.217287828 , 512527.368342418 , 512526.187479454 ,
     512525.66807419 ,  512525.155055254 , 512524.123425993 , 512523.333620799 , 512522.845719099 , 512522.493475288 , 512522.02414975 ,  512521.707617408 ,
     512521.414032635 , 512521.272723958 , 512521.003438704 , 512520.611198348 , 512520.044358903 , 512519.883403295 , 512519.581804837 , 512519.401724859 ,
     512519.226393887 , 512518.908757327 , 512518.677251262 , 512518.383111624 , 512518.125986409 , 512517.891754541 , 512517.579340079 , 512517.294601343 ,
     512516.534844996 , 512516.232402901 , 512515.910507093 , 512515.564246133 , 512515.221423256 , 512514.971887748 , 512514.669375889 , 512514.571434083 ,
     512514.253105538 , 512514.082025203 , 512513.747593368 , 512513.700478408 , 512513.349890152 , 512513.261851035 , 512512.712619034 , 512512.097684535 ,
     512512 ,           512512.006544385 , 512512.02498364 ,  512512.712619034 , 512507.157200324 , 512507.544439412 , 512512.712619034 , 512492.586731394 ,
     512494.556199353 , 512495.235072968 , 512496.064112409 , 512496.311072031 , 512496.637229679 , 512496.838057973 , 512497.158693114 , 512497.534620225 ,
     512497.847948322 , 512498.150219877 , 512498.454494612 , 512498.671801076 , 512499.343740123 , 512499.568181757 , 512499.972352636 , 512500.200692716 ,
     512500.454522548 , 512500.686574989 , 512500.869130695 , 512501.28349144 ,  512501.517356646 , 512501.904607063 , 512503.008985698 , 512503.272686664 ,
     512503.900668267 , 512504.215076556 , 512504.471659978 , 512504.784537156 , 512505.032728834 , 512505.339041358 , 512505.757924357 , 512506.218528546 ,
     512506.656969083 , 512507.456461994 , 512507.923405741 , 512509.446858774 , 512510.916227406 , 512511.260548276 , 512511.940773104 , 512512.080641235 ,
     512512.732295137 , 512512.832913485 , 512512.544714271 , 512512.097684535 , 512512.269086673 , 512512.294417801 , 512512.29539941 ,  512512.256515058 ,
     512512.544714271 , 512549.195740681 , 512549.504464303 , 512549.615775818 , 512550.05706312 ,  512550.294048221 , 512550.563069153 , 512550.805049173 ,
     512551.877228774 , 512552.138405963 , 512552.452242581 , 512553.612261229 , 512554.231688528 , 512554.897676925 , 512555.026613213 , 512555.285111796 ,
     512555.403889146 , 512555.559892224 , 512555.665627616 , 512555.829303864 , 512555.918834597 , 512556.091281272 , 512556.161299882 , 512556.29685421 , 
     512556.334599458 , 512556.523882052 , 512556.547546865 , 512556.695796547 , 512556.704268122 , 512557.015234229 , 512557.001384996 , 512557.217040051 ,
     512557.187046448 , 512557.351367066 , 512557.571243187 , 512557.524181427 , 512557.687564349 , 512557.623565981 , 512557.835948975 , 512557.755492166 ,
     512557.908204675 , 512557.812104296 , 512558.092245563 , 512558.215978661 , 512415.384159413 , 512415.190382715 , 512414.957578414 , 512414.898012412 ,
     512414.558488979 , 512414.067211799 , 512413.638307348 , 512413.419640465 , 512413.24907239 ,  512412.589339638 , 512412.440848364 , 512412.295916573 ,
     512412.153275912 , 512411.533145835 , 512411.412878189 , 512411.34087791 ,  512411.292126322 , 512411.268620724 , 512410.418976001 , 512410.419473156 ,
     512410.444374562 , 512410.495616667 , 512410.249109005 , 512410.326740391 , 512410.430697842 , 512410.171190017 , 512410.301374468 , 512410.04923823 , 
     512410.181550106 , 512410.062466312 , 512410.16110783 ,  512410.048053736 , 512410.127340298 , 512410.021076678 , 512410.104721863 , 512410.006700549 ,
     512410.094466192 , 512409.994326209 , 512410.085904982 , 512409.983965338 , 512410.078979306 , 512409.975637993 , 512410.073641847 , 512409.969366909 ,
     512410.069855885 , 512409.965172951 , 512410.067594993 , 512410.17136635 ,  512471.012634321 , 512470.230354115 , 512469.591030456 , 512469.321345479 ,
     512468.650056948 , 512468.203552182 , 512467.732139706 , 512467.219223363 , 512466.867185175 , 512466.716848874 , 512466.475889951 , 512466.256501471 ,
     512466.109923706 , 512466.001240639 , 512465.867649463 , 512465.779859319 , 512465.556429178 , 512465.49283629 ,  512465.404718517 , 512465.377442848 ,
     512465.305711549 , 512465.289928503 , 512465.234705359 , 512465.265158684)
    
    
     
    y <- c(6018724.17256768 , 6018724.0306637 ,  6018723.40160793 , 6018723.02062054 , 6018719.63978774 , 6018719.8859143 ,  6018719.94169498 , 6018720.19904659 ,
      6018720.27865743 , 6018720.55930264 , 6018720.7783321 ,  6018720.9822937 ,  6018721.53062273 , 6018721.77786335 , 6018722.12486027 , 6018722.45502615 ,
     6018722.63963316 , 6018723.02062054 , 6018750.38515942 , 6018749.83393612 , 6018749.3522271 ,  6018749.16086242 , 6018747.28558407 , 6018746.8286612 , 
     6018746.34995216 , 6018745.83799267 , 6018745.4150896 ,  6018744.97604772 , 6018744.47067641 , 6018743.98022566 , 6018742.81206217 , 6018742.33654506 ,
     6018741.62211734 , 6018741.16509384 , 6018740.54478237 , 6018740.16146164 , 6018739.56861923 , 6018739.14781669 , 6018738.64700381 , 6018738.23009501 ,
     6018737.77252191 , 6018737.32022009 , 6018736.89238009 , 6018736.48726854 , 6018736.10334914 , 6018735.73905685 , 6018733.20545472 , 6018732.81608795 ,
    6018732.16072207 , 6018731.90271977 , 6018724.17256768 , 6018724.31447166 , 6018724.42087314 , 6018724.59475322 , 6018724.81339919 , 6018724.97746768 ,
     6018725.08131377 , 6018725.21902713 , 6018725.45213798 , 6018725.49387016 , 6018725.71183302 , 6018725.69306437 , 6018725.88704867 , 6018725.8283917 , 
     6018725.68065223 , 6018725.83568443 , 6018725.77455507 , 6018725.86768213 , 6018725.81907717 , 6018725.890826 ,   6018725.85065988 , 6018725.91135793 ,
     6018725.88277965 , 6018725.98217341 , 6018725.92307067 , 6018726.01992979 , 6018725.90485765 , 6018725.99335776 , 6018725.97951027 , 6018726.13159947 ,
     6018726.18139745 , 6018726.42522556 , 6018726.54246534 , 6018726.66114572 , 6018726.77623503 , 6018726.85613586 , 6018726.99355597 , 6018727.05842898 ,
     6018727.21817651 , 6018727.30036941 , 6018727.45943706 , 6018727.56183975 , 6018727.66943651 , 6018727.87523819 , 6018728.0805324 ,  6018728.49831224 ,
     6018728.72597842 , 6018729.13821392 , 6018729.42762614 , 6018729.67704739 , 6018729.84546524 , 6018729.98126248 , 6018731.90271977 , 6018731.64471747 ,
     6018730.55087195 , 6018730.11705971 , 6018729.98126248 , 6018741.69410277 , 6018741.95138423 , 6018742.30121788 , 6018742.21084514 , 6018742.13902167 ,
     6018742.62883081 , 6018742.57545308 , 6018742.86020423 , 6018742.824961 ,   6018743.22389503 , 6018743.20626876 , 6018743.37006651 , 6018743.36934668 ,
     6018743.52481695 , 6018743.54012033 , 6018743.82874009 , 6018743.8667927 ,  6018744.03421474 , 6018744.08096629 , 6018744.39104616 , 6018744.46331616 ,
     6018744.63578763 , 6018744.75719823 , 6018744.92123852 , 6018745.12068056 , 6018745.47823272 , 6018745.70998456 , 6018746.49527914 , 6018747.1086068 , 
     6018747.4833455 ,  6018747.66148792 , 6018748.76465966 , 6018748.99199995 , 6018749.64944729 , 6018750.37201792 , 6018750.77031684 , 6018751.16880956 ,
     6018751.37274339 , 6018751.54296756 , 6018751.76738948 , 6018751.94618466 , 6018752.69608177 , 6018753.18136297 , 6018753.64665368 , 6018753.84298549 ,
     6018753.9208185 ,  6018754.04189476 , 6018754.20207589 , 6018775.26875698 , 6018775.57224221 , 6018777.34231691 , 6018777.62824329 , 6018777.79828808 ,
     6018777.952843 ,   6018778.23331304 , 6018778.66155332 , 6018779.11595371 , 6018779.90007012 , 6018780.19462072 , 6018780.95493064 , 6018781.90970758 ,
     6018783.21615613 , 6018784.20503877 , 6018784.68037312 , 6018785.15359118 , 6018785.61493291 , 6018786.06552706 , 6018786.98075993 , 6018787.48187168 ,
     6018787.9404781 ,  6018789.39805548 , 6018790.803202 ,   6018792.50178588 , 6018793.057836 ,   6018793.34708878 , 6018793.95107191 , 6018795.98310696 ,
     6018796.63319137 , 6018797.30469617 , 6018797.99547212 , 6018798.61855064 , 6018799.41192188 , 6018800.82747026 , 6018802.42520342 , 6018803.50560138 ,
     6018803.72506298 , 6018803.88685867 , 6018804.25998658 , 6018804.98963855 , 6018806.07098216 , 6018806.21025854 , 6018775.26875698 , 6018774.96527174 ,
     6018774.71142004 , 6018774.1660715 ,  6018773.04897571 , 6018772.55174872 , 6018771.07359188 , 6018770.50371218 , 6018769.07565759 , 6018766.79152056 ,
     6018765.82592582 , 6018764.75494476 , 6018762.81657401 , 6018761.01378522 , 6018760.01668692 , 6018759.19952472 , 6018758.18385026 , 6018757.3123826 , 
     6018756.71496737 , 6018756.26227605 , 6018755.7395613 ,  6018754.34980166 , 6018753.33264113 , 6018752.80059674 , 6018752.31019531 , 6018751.79727529 ,
     6018751.37860626 , 6018750.90424346 , 6018750.44274952 , 6018750.04389156 , 6018749.60801678 , 6018749.24824864 , 6018748.86767175 , 6018748.55843263 ,
     6018747.43718898 , 6018747.14568889 , 6018746.87372654 , 6018746.3289875 ,  6018746.07813808 , 6018745.63467359 , 6018745.44274083 , 6018745.24368263 ,
     6018745.06803395 , 6018744.64511429 , 6018744.48635802 , 6018744.33547297 , 6018744.19415146 , 6018743.78719057 , 6018743.56140693 , 6018736.75794849 ,
     6018737 ,          6018737.68645562 , 6018737.96501637 , 6018743.56140693 , 6018741.69410277 , 6018741.43682132 , 6018743.56140693 , 6018719.63978774 ,
     6018719.43692428 , 6018720.05728691 , 6018720.02117234 , 6018720.23023286 , 6018720.23936909 , 6018720.39462691 , 6018720.41962841 , 6018720.66324041 ,
     6018720.70537524 , 6018720.85885136 , 6018720.91901093 , 6018721.00118329 , 6018721.19914364 , 6018721.24607707 , 6018721.41800448 , 6018721.44596966 ,
     6018721.58110303 , 6018721.59200183 , 6018721.70296151 , 6018721.68935159 , 6018721.84852011 , 6018722.15187047 , 6018722.05191479 , 6018722.28259925 ,
     6018722.28227114 , 6018722.31505534 , 6018722.55323573 , 6018722.61164417 , 6018722.67747766 , 6018722.783499 ,   6018722.97415942 , 6018723.24639234 ,
     6018723.56742839 , 6018724.35178165 , 6018724.75827059 , 6018726.2934096 ,  6018727.88511806 , 6018728.3079817 ,  6018729.0137024 ,  6018729.23777764 ,
     6018729.87311987 , 6018730.10850437 , 6018732.9727036 ,  6018736.75794849 , 6018736.33217335 , 6018736.20756475 , 6018736.02047542 , 6018735.83690282 ,
     6018732.9727036 ,  6018806.21025854 , 6018806.34953492 , 6018806.4362234 ,  6018806.6879361 ,  6018806.846951 ,   6018807.07293007 , 6018807.32595005 ,
     6018809.42156328 , 6018809.75438609 , 6018810.23254938 , 6018812.21074509 , 6018813.39809422 , 6018814.59696559 , 6018814.85430618 , 6018815.2759903 , 
     6018815.53655282 , 6018815.76429167 , 6018816.02755388 , 6018816.2423029 ,  6018816.50716333 , 6018816.70599025 , 6018816.97073596 , 6018817.10759483 ,
     6018817.30470823 , 6018817.46843808 , 6018817.66301691 , 6018817.77017755 , 6018817.96089484 , 6018818.1301878 ,  6018818.37596671 , 6018818.45241119 ,
     6018818.62838362 , 6018818.66530778 , 6018818.68632017 , 6018818.85339567 , 6018818.84758275 , 6018819.00422157 , 6018818.96754504 , 6018819.11226443 ,
     6018819.06325584 , 6018819.19466471 , 6018819.04317046 , 6018818.94204485 , 6018750.38515942 , 6018750.93638272 , 6018751.49557841 , 6018751.73301241 ,
     6018752.58148898 , 6018753.57521179 , 6018754.73030734 , 6018755.20464045 , 6018755.6280724 ,  6018757.54233937 , 6018758.08684611 , 6018758.7338869 , 
     6018759.48195681 , 6018761.33680292 , 6018762.10572162 , 6018762.72167369 , 6018763.3531075 ,  6018763.99514741 , 6018766.60564113 , 6018767.15825611 ,
     6018767.79743739 , 6018768.42224184 , 6018769.15436388 , 6018769.75677692 , 6018770.32863655 , 6018771.02783437 , 6018771.55906322 , 6018772.13302141 ,
     6018772.54596878 , 6018772.77547756 , 6018773.02366777 , 6018773.21387219 , 6018773.3833927 ,  6018773.54361682 , 6018773.6972747 ,  6018773.82366555 ,
     6018773.96004626 , 6018774.07004851 , 6018774.1878309 ,  6018774.28006821 , 6018774.37807783 , 6018774.45129258 , 6018774.52855044 , 6018774.58164681 ,
     6018774.63741055 , 6018774.66949525 , 6018774.7032899 ,  6018774.71492659 , 6018754.20207589 , 6018754.36225702 , 6018754.60882005 , 6018754.73159114 ,
     6018754.72981139 , 6018754.9653672 ,  6018754.94803884 , 6018755.2903379 ,  6018755.25886132 , 6018755.38258098 , 6018755.34434349 , 6018755.55997439 ,
     6018755.52631977 , 6018755.66023572 , 6018755.61960703 , 6018755.75559819 , 6018755.65310924 , 6018755.78962009 , 6018755.72814677 , 6018755.81848268 ,
     6018755.75076722 , 6018755.8835557 ,  6018755.81022106 , 6018755.97814886)
     
    
    NEW_ID <- rep(18, each = 420)

    LINE_ID <- c(rep(1, each = 4), rep(2, each = 14), rep(3, each = 32), rep(4, each = 52), rep(5, each = 5), rep(6, each = 48), rep(7, each = 43), 
             rep(8, each = 49), rep(9, each = 5), rep(10, each = 3), rep(11, each = 44), rep(12, each = 6), rep(13, each = 43), rep(14, each = 48), rep(15, each = 24))
```

Maybe someone knows how to work around this?

(I think maybe it also is an issue that my points in the dataframe come from several Linestrings that are in a list. But because I want to combine them into one Linestring I put all coordinates into a dataframe.) (Edit: I added Line-IDs to the coordinates in case it is important. The IDs come from the separate Linestrings I want to combine.)

Comment: I'm afraid the order of those points in your dataframe does not match your expectations  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/utJzb.png . When grouping by `LINE_ID`, you should get valid line segments. though order of those segments would still be off. I would expect the real `LINE_ID` to be something different, based on time or sequence, thus defining the correct order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be the grouping factor (NEW_ID). When grouping by LINE_ID the `group_by() %>% summarise() %>% cast()` pipeline appears to work fine.

```
test_lines <- data.frame(x, y, NEW_ID, LINE_ID)

new_lines <- test_lines %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 25832) %>%
  group_by(LINE_ID) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(do_union=FALSE) %>%  # do_union=FALSE doesn't work as well
  st_cast("LINESTRING") 

ggplot() + geom_sf(data=new_lines, aes(color=as.factor(LINE_ID)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of that. I'll try to work around NEW_ID then

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one group, `group_by`, `summarize`, `union` does not work. Instead try this:

```
# Sample dataframe with latitude and longitude
data <- data.frame(
  longitude = c(-122.4194, -122.4195),
  latitude = c(37.7749, 37.7750)
)

# Convert the dataframe to an sf object
sf_object <- st_as_sf(data, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)

# Convert points to a linestring
linestring <- st_combine(sf_object) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")

plot(st_geometry(linestring))
```

[image]